# Sortable and hidden information through nested accordion in HTML/PHP page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So i am trying to display data in sql server using PHP. I am using a sortable library i found online and this is my code:

```
 echo "<table id='report' class='sortable'>";
        echo "<thead><tr>";
            echo "<th>A</th>";
            echo "<th>B</th>";
            echo "<th>C</th>";
            echo "<th>D</th>";
            echo "<th>E</th>";
            echo "<th>F</th>";
            echo "<th>G</th>";
            echo "<th>H</th>";
            echo "<th>I</th>"; 
        echo "</tr></thead>";
        echo "<tbody>";

        for($i=0; $i<$tablerows; $i++)
        {                
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$result[$i]['A']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result[$i]['B']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result[$i]['C']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result[$i]['D']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result[$i]['E']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result[$i]['F']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result[$i]['G']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result[$i]['H']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$result[$i]['I']."</td>";
                echo "<td><div class='arrow'></div></td>";
            echo "</tr>";  
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan='5'>";
                echo "<div id='nestedAccordion'>";
                    echo "<h2>COLUMN 1 ELABORATE</h2>";
                        echo "<div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "<h2>COLUMN 2 ELABORATE</h2>";
                        echo "<div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "<h2>COLUMN 3 ELABORATE</h2>";
                        echo "<div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "<h2>COLUMN 4 ELABORATE</h2>";
                        echo "<div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    echo "<h2>COLUMN 5 ELABORATE</h2>";
                        echo "<div>";
                        echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
```

When my page is loaded, it can be sorted by the A-I headings in `<th>` tag. As you can see, in my 'for' loop my last tag has an arrow. I want that so if the user wants more information about the row, he can view that by clicking that arrow, and information that will be displayed is in: `<td colspan='5'>`

Here is the javascript/jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#report tr:first-child").show();
    $(".arrow").click(function(){
        $(this).parents("tr").next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("up");
    });

    var parentDivs = $('#nestedAccordion div'),
    childDivs = $('#nestedAccordion h3').siblings('div');
    $('#nestedAccordion h2').click(function () {
        parentDivs.slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
        }
    });

    $('#nestedAccordion h3').click(function () {
        childDivs.slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

The question and the problem i have is only either sortable for table or arrow will work. When i load the page, and i click on the arrow to view more information i can view it, but if i sort afterward, the data under the arrow is taken as its own row rather than part of the row it was selected from.
If i sort at start, and then click on arrow, the row below is hidden. I think the problem is in this chunk of code:

```
$(".arrow").click(function(){
    $(this).parents("tr").next("tr").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass("up");
});
```

Since the next tr is for colspan? But how do i fix it?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: Nevermind, i figured it the problem is with sortable library.